# Slider desaparece en versión movil/tablets

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un sitio Wordpress creado con plantilla en el que el slider desaparece al visualizarlo desde celular o tablet (Creo que no es problema del responsive o viewport porque en la versión de escritorio se ve bien al encoger la ventana). He probado a usar diferentes plugins de sliders, desactivar todos los plugins y volver a activarlos uno a uno y el problema persiste, por lo que creo que es un problema con el PHP del template de la web, pero no doy con la solución. Al visualizarlo en el navegador de un teléfono o tablet parece cargar el slider pero de pronto salta y desaparece quedando en blanco, creo que debe cambiar a una página nueva al entrar desde el móvil. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

http://www.lapinatasd.com

Muchas gracias,
Un saludo!

```html
<?php /* Template Name: Home Page */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <!-- BEGIN HOME SLIDER SECTION -->
              <section id="home-slider">
<?php putRevSlider( 'home' ); ?>
   </section>
    <!-- END HOME SLIDER SECTION -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $back = $post //backup post data?>
<?php $child_sections = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' =>'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); ?>
<?php while ($child_sections->have_posts() ) : $child_sections->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $bg = rwmb_meta( '_jellythemes_section_bg', 'type=image', get_the_ID() );  foreach ($bg as $bg_image) : $bg_url = $bg_image['full_url']; endforeach; ?>
    <?php $bg2 = rwmb_meta( '_jellythemes_section_bg2', 'type=image', get_the_ID() );  foreach ($bg2 as $bg_image2) : $bg_url2 = $bg_image2['full_url']; endforeach; ?>
    <?php $video = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_parallax_video', true ); ?>
    <?php if (empty($video)): ?>
        <section id="<?php echo esc_attr($post->post_name); ?>" class="section <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_section_type', true ); ?> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_section_color', true ); ?>" style="background-color:<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_bg_color', true ); ?>; <?php echo (!empty($bg_url) ? 'background-image: url(' . $bg_url . ')' . (!empty($bg_url2) ? ', url(' . $bg_url2 . ')' : '') . ';'  : ''); ?>">
            <div class="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_section_width', true ); ?>">
                <?php the_content(); ?> 
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php else: ?>
        <section id="<?php echo esc_attr($post->post_name); ?>" class="player section" data-property="{videoURL:'<?php echo esc_js($video); ?>',containment:'self',autoPlay:true, mute:true, startAt:0,opacity:1,ratio:'4/3', addRaster:true}">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <?php $logos = rwmb_meta('_jellythemes_bg_logo', 'type=image', $post->ID ); ?>
            <?php foreach ($logos as $logo) : ?>
            <img class="video-img" src="<?php echo esc_url($logo['full_url']); ?>" alt="video">
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </section>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php $bg_url=''; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php $post = $back //restore post data?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si crees que el problema es de PHP, deja tu codigo!

Comment: Gracias @sioesi he añadido el código php del Home page template que está activo en la web pero creo que el que salta en la versión móvil debe ser otro distinto al que no consigo acceder o encontrar, alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: Pasa el html, cuando no aparece en dispositivos móviles es porque hay alguna clase que esta con el atributo display: none en el css

Comment: Puedes ver el código fuente html de mi web aquí---> view-source:http://www.lapinatasd.com/ Gracias @Genarito

Comment: He usado un *Samsung Note3*, he visitado la web con *Google Chrome* y todos los `sliders` funcionan a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

¿Podés fijarte en el settings del slider, en la parte donde dice "Layout & Visual", en la tab "Mobile"?

Puede estar activada la opción "Disable Slider on Mobile".

El viewport está bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estaba desactivada :(